# windows phone silverlight font-awesome and appbar icon

Tags: xaml, silverlight, windows-phone-8, font-awesome, appbar

I am making a windows phone 8 silverlight app. And I am using **font-awesome** icons on my app's mainpage.. they do display in the designer properly but when I run the app on emulator they don't display properly.

Also I am using normal **76 X 76 px PNG** file images for appbar icons and they are not even displayed properly in the designer, they do not fit within the circle of the appbar icon, rather they try to escape the **circle**. I am attacking the image/screenshot from the emulator below, you can see and please tell me the solution. **Thanks in advance**

**Image From Emulator**

[image: Image From Emulator]

**Image From Designer of visual studio**

[image: Image from designer of visual studio]

**XAML Code For ApplicationBar**

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
    <shell:ApplicationBar>
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Assets/AppBar/scan.png"
                                        IsEnabled="True"
                                        Text="Scan"/>
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Assets/AppBar/search.png"
                                        IsEnabled="True"
                                        Text="Search"/>
    </shell:ApplicationBar>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
```

**Application Resource for MainPage Icon TextBlocks**

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary >
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock"
               x:Key="MainPageIcon">
            <Setter Property="FontSize"
                    Value="80" />
            <Setter Property="Width"
                    Value="90" />
            <Setter Property="FontFamily"
                    Value="/Resources/FontAwesome.otf#FontAwesome" />
            <Setter Property="TextAlignment"
                    Value="Center" />
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

**XAML for one of the icons on mainpage**

```
<TextBlock Text="&#xf02a;"  Style="{StaticResource MainPageIcon}"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, picture size doesn't matter. What's important - it's a transparent borders around actual icon. Add wide transparent borders around actual images and you'll be allset.

Incorrect image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNuJg.png

Correct image:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPdRc.png

VS XAML designer screenshot:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Jgpg.png

Emulator screenshot:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZuCUE.png

Comment: To make QR image smaller, add semi-transparent (even with 0.1 transparency) borders between transparent borders and actual image.

Comment: No, you don't understand: you should use any image editor, even online like http://pixlr.com/editor/

Open your icons in the editor, and increase canvas size (for pixlr.com it's an menu Image->Canvas size...)